# C# Added Ajax Update Panel but Anchor will not run server-side code once placeholder is populated

Tags: c#, ajax

I've just been told I need to update my links from posting back so I added an Ajax Update Panel to handle the requests instead so there isn't a postback. My links are generated from the codebehind and populate a placeholder. I need to update the code so that it will be able to run server side code. I have tried programmatically adding via controls.add but I couldn't get anything to run server side code.

```
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        eventListCounter++;
                        string strEventTitle = myReader["eventTitle"].ToString();
                        string strEventThumb = myReader["eventThumb"].ToString();
                        string strEventInfo = myReader["eventInfo"].ToString();
                        int eventID = Int32.Parse(myReader["ID"].ToString());
                        strHTML += "<div class='styleWeekRedCarpetEventBox'><div class='styleWeekRedCarpetPictureBox'>";
                        strHTML +="<a href='RedCarpet.aspx?eventID=" + eventID.ToString() +"'  runat='server' id='linkEventShowImageSet'><img Width='125' Height='95'src='Images/" + strEventThumb.ToString() + "' border='0'></a></div><div id='styleWeekRedCarpetPictureBoxText'><p><a href='RedCarpet.aspx?eventID=" + eventID + "' runat='server' id='linkEventShowImageSet'><b>" + strEventTitle.ToString() + "</b><br />" + strEventInfo.ToString() + "</a></p></div></div><br><br>";

                        if (eventListCounter == 5)
                        {
                            strHTML += "</div><div class=\"eventListColumn\">";
                            eventListCounter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception strError)
                    {
                        Response.Write(strError.ToString());
                    }


                }
                LiteralControl eventListPlaceholder = new LiteralControl(strHTML.ToString());
                PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(eventListPlaceholder);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the perfect place to use a [repeater control](http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/), you should shy away from using `Response.Write` and let the framework abstract that away from you.

There is a high chance this this will solve the event not being fired server-side.

Comment: The contents of this output lives in divs within in a jquery carousel. I am limited on what I can do.  I am fairly overhwelmed and any help you can give me modifying the above code would be appreciated...

Comment: I can understand that - Have you looked the produced HTML in the browser?  This may point towards the solution.

Comment: Yes, the output have the `runat='server'` tags still present in the code which means, to me, they aren't being compiled as controls.

Comment: That would be correct - because they're being rendered as literal ;-)

Comment: Self-taught old guy here.. Ok, so the literal is just passing text through and would be adequate if I did not need to fire serverside code.  So, how would I use the repeater in the case above? How much you charge me to dig in and fix it?